# Difference between "not any" and "no any"

Tags: negation, determiners, quantifiers

I'm wondering what the difference between "There is no any type of harm done to animals" and "There is not any type of harm done to animals" is? Moreover, in contracting the negative phrase "There isn't", does it differ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "There was **no** harm done to the animals" vs. "there was **not any** harm done to the animals"?  "No any" is not grammatical.

Comment: "No any" is nonsensical in English.

Comment: It does not matter if the tense differs, does it?

Comment: Thank you, Andrew and P. E. Dant, for your informative notes.

Comment: Does it differ if it's contracted?

Comment: _There isn't any_ is identical in meaning to _there is not any._ Tense doesn't make any difference, either. _There wasn't any_ is identical in meaning to _there was not any._

Comment: @Johnny I changed to past tense because "There is not any harm done to the animals" is not natural English.  Rather, I would say, "The animals aren't being harmed," if the action is happening in the present moment, or "The animals have not been harmed" if the action took place in the past.

Comment: Scots sometimes use "no" to mean "not". It's common to hear a Scot saying: "I am no...." meaning "I am not". But this is spoken rather than written English. (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_Scottish_slang_and_jargon)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no any & There is no](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56791/there-is-no-any-there-is-no)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*No any* is ungrammatical, you can use *no* or *not any*.There is no difference in meaning between *There is/are no + noun* and *There isn’t/aren’t any + noun*:

> There was no reason to be afraid of her. (or There wasn't  any reason to be afraid of her.)

No + noun often makes the negative stronger, "no"gives more emphasis.  In speaking, *no* is often stressed.

Comment: I highly appreciate you.